# How to run an action when clicking on an appindicator

Tags: application-development, python, indicator

I'm looking at writing a simple app indicator and I need it to update it's information whenever it's clicked on to open the menu. Is there any kind of on_click action thing?

Let me rephrase it then: How to perform an action (any action) when the user clicks on the appindicator to open its menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An app indicator can only open its menu. It can't perform any other action and your program doesn't get notified when the menu is displayed.

You could either include some kind of "Update" menu item or find other events that trigger the update.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that might be it. I'll look into other events that might trigger this instead.

Comment: @DoGoDo, have you found any solution?

Comment: So there is no click event emitted? That just seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the middle mouse click in one of my indicators to perform an action, so I think you could do the same... See related [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/501050/67335).

*Note it only seems to work on Ubuntu (not Lubuntu/Xubuntu).*

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you may notice that some indicators (like volume or keyboard language ones) support middle mouse click. It can be done with `set_secondary_activate_target(menu_item)`.
My code snippet for pyGtk/pyGI:

```
    menu_items = Gtk.MenuItem("Toggle Floater")
    menu.append(menu_items)
    menu_items.connect("activate", self.toggleWindow)
    self.ind.set_secondary_activate_target(menu_items)
```

I found it [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/python/AppIndicator3-0.1.html), but it's not described, I just tried it on chance, and it worked.

Comment: Do you think you can share how you applied the code block to your code?  When I use `self` as part of my code, I get errors in the IDE `undefined variable:self`.  If I use the name of the defined indicator there are no errors in the IDE.  But fails to run giving the errors in the error block included in this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/930848/29012.