# How to program a one click indicator (add middle click functionality)?

Tags: unity, python, application-development, indicator

I'm fairly fluent with creating Application indicators with menus.  On the example below there is one menu item (quit).  I wouldn't have any problems adding another item, my actual application, or line to run.

However, when I'm trying to do is make the item run when the indicator icon is clicked.  Each time the indicator icon is clicked it will run.  To remove the indicator icon, the user will click on quit.

Can someone tell me where to put my line to run in the code?

**This is the indicator code:**

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import signal
import subprocess
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

APPINDICATOR_ID = 'appreveallauncher'


def main():
    indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID,
                                            os.path.abspath('sample_icon.svg'),
                                            appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
    indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    indicator.set_menu(build_menu())
    gtk.main()

def build_menu():
    menu = gtk.Menu()

    item_quit1 = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    item_quit1.connect('activate', quit)

    item_reveallauncher = gtk.MenuItem('Reveal Launcher')
    item_reveallauncher.connect('activate', reveallauncher)

    # This is my attempt to add the middle click functionality

    menu_items = gtk.MenuItem("Reveal Launcher Middle Click")
    menu.append(menu_items)
    menu_items.connect("activate", menu_items)
    menu_items.set_secondary_activate_target(menu_items)    


    menu.append(item_reveallauncher)
    menu.append(item_quit1)
    menu.show_all()
    return menu

def menu_items(_):
    subprocess.call("xdotool key alt+F1", shell=True) 


def reveallauncher(_):
    subprocess.call("xdotool key alt+F1", shell=True) 

def quit1(_):
    gtk.main_quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    main()

#   last = self.get_last_menuitem(self.app_menu) 
#   self.app.set_secondary_activate_target(last)
```

**Here is the line:**

```python
subprocess.call("xdotool key alt+F1", shell=True)
```

This is the error when running the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/l/j/ljames/workspace/pythontest/src/basic.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/users/l/j/ljames/workspace/pythontest/src/basic.py", line 19, in main
    indicator.set_menu(build_menu())
  File "/home/users/l/j/ljames/workspace/pythontest/src/basic.py", line 35, in build_menu
    menu_items.connect("activate", menu_items)
TypeError: second argument must be callable
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the Ubuntu Launcher reveal when the indicator is clicked.

**Update**

I have updated my code sample above to include the lines of the desired action.  Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy has indicated in his answer the middle click resolution.  I commented the necessary lines at the bottom.  Now I'm trying to get the right syntax and position for those lines.

Comment: Same question, by the way, likely a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/224709/295286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the errors and apply the middleclick functionality to the code in question (while there may be many alterternative methods), I added an argument to the `build_menu` statement in the main si that the `build_menu` definition can take an argument.  I called this argument `indicator`.  Then added the middleclick method, `set_secondary_activate_target()`.

**The fixed code:**

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import signal
import subprocess
import gi
from middleClick import reveallauncher
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

APPINDICATOR_ID = 'appreveallauncher'

def main():
    indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID,
                os.path.abspath('sample_icon.svg'),
                appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
    indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    indicator.set_menu(build_menu(indicator))
    gtk.main()

def build_menu(indicator):
    menu = gtk.Menu()

    item_reveallauncher = gtk.MenuItem('Reveal Launcher')
    item_reveallauncher.connect('activate', reveallauncher)   
    indicator.set_secondary_activate_target(item_reveallauncher)

    item_quit = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    item_quit.connect('activate', quit)

    menu.append(item_reveallauncher)
    menu.append(item_quit)
    menu.show_all()
    return menu

def reveallauncher(_):
    subprocess.call("xdotool key alt+F1", shell=True) 

def quit(_):
    gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    main()
```

There are a number of example usages of the `set_secondary_activate_target` method that can be found by Google searches.  However, the problem I experienced is that they are all included in a complex script used in a way of many dependent lines.  This is an effort to put it in a most simplified example to make it easier for the next person trying to adapt it to their code.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that you can't. Clicking on indicator icon only brings up the menu. What can be done is to set the middle (scrollwheel) click ( on touchpads that's right and left click pressed together ), which is done by setting Indicator object's secondary activate target.

Here's an example of something I use within my own [launcher-list-indicator](https://github.com/SergKolo/launcher-list-indicator) on lines 152 and 153:

```
152         last = self.get_last_menuitem(self.app_menu)
153         self.app.set_secondary_activate_target(last)
```

When user presses middle click over idicator item, it will activate the specific menu-item without bringing down the menu.

What you also can do as alternative, is to use scroll events, something like that:

```
86         self.app.connect("scroll-event", self.set_next)
```

Comment: Thanks.  When I get back to my shop I'll study your suggestions.

Comment: @L.D.James you're welcome. I know this is not exactly ideal answer, but that's the best I've found over time. I've perused the documentation on indicators and searched online, but that's the closest I found to icon-clicking in appindicators

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy You can't simply kill an application indicator?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix   You can kill the process, sure, but that's not what we're talking about here. L.D.James wants to perform an action when indicator icon is clicked, as if it were a button.  Unfortunatelly, like I already said, it doesn't work that way

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Oh I misread. I thought his indicator had two options: `1. Run Foo-Bar` and `2. Quit Foo-Bar`.

Comment: Thanks for the info that it's not possible to have an indicator run as if it were a button.  I don't know if I should add more details to the question to ask if there is a way outside of using the template, to have access to the `onclick` routine (wherever it happens to be/in the indicate library or a gtk library), then tread off and run the desired command.

Comment: @L.D.James I somehow doubt that's also possible. There's no signal for menu being open, so even if we do regular click, there's no way to detect that event

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Your **launcher-list-indicator** has the exact functionality that I'm trying to achieve.  The key solution, as you have indicated is the **middle-click** feature of the indicator.  I have spent a lot of time trying to add the two lines to my code.  I get errors that **self** isn't defined.  When I try to use the actual defined menu item **reveal launcher** (`reveallauncher.set_secondary_activate_target(reveallauncher))`) it returns other errors.  I'm still studying the way it's implimented in your package, but the code is quiet complex for my limited python experience.

Comment: @L.D.James `self` always refers to the class. If you notice, in my code I'm creating `class LauncherListIndicator()`.  Your code is doing the same thing, just shorter, all within `main()` function.  I can provide an example tomorrow, but essentially  I'd suggest you do same as this: https://askubuntu.com/a/731145/295286  In your main function add another menu item, and use `indicator.set_secondary_activate_target(that_menu_item)`

Comment: Thanks.  I had used a number of combinations from that answer also.  I'll focus on it more.  I understood about the `self` and tried to define a self for the program.  I understand that the problem that I'm having is quite simple (for someone who knows Python).  Rather than include every variation that I had tested, I picked a starting point for my last comment to you.  I was adding a more specific error message to my question at the same time that you posted your last comment.  I'm glad that it appears I'm kind of on the right track of where to focus.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I thought I had done your last suggestion exactly (as part of the countless variations that I have tried).  I was using the `indicator` as the name of a new menu item, following what appeared to exist in the previous https://askubuntu.com/a/731145/295286 answer.  I used a number of names including the name `indicator` for `indicator.set_secondary_activate_target(new_menu_item)`.  I can get it programmed into Eclipse without errors, but so far every combination that I have used had given he same error that is in the error section in my question.

Comment: By the way, I appreciate your consideration to provide an example tomorrow.  If I stumble on a combination that works, I'll advise.  Otherwise, I won't keep bombarding you with the many combinations from the other question and this one that I've tried.